# Python: Why does returning a string change it to a list (of length one)

Tags: python, list, return

I'm creating a string in a method and returning it. But I get back a list in stead of a string.

```
def method():
    string1 = "hallo1 \nhallo2"
    print("string1 :")
    print(type(string1))
    print(string1)
    return[string1]    

string2=method()
print("string2 :")
print(type(string2))
print(string2)
```

I would suspect both string1 and string2 to be of type string and be identical, in stead I get the following output:

```
string1 :
<class 'str'>
hallo1
hallo2
string2 :
<class 'list'>
['hallo1 \nhallo2']
```

Suspected/wanted output:

```
string1 :
<class 'str'>
hallo1
hallo2
string2 :
<class 'str'>
hallo1
hallo2
```

I do have experience with code, but I haven't been in school for 10 years, and haven't coded much since, also I have no real Python experience, so I could well be I'm missing something simple/stupid.

My google skills left me with nothing here, so I'm hoping someone here can shed some light on what is happening.

Comment: Simply because you put `[]` around the return value.

Comment: What do you expect `return[string1]` to do? Are you trying to call `return` as if it were a function? You just want `return string1`.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a particularly good place for asking tutorial-level questions about programming languages.

Comment: Putting square brackets around an expression puts it into a list.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It's bad for "how to" questions, it's fine for "why does this do X?" questions about actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you wrote in code `return [string1]`
This instructs python to return a `list` with a single element `string1` as the return value from `method`.

Accordingly its type is `list` and not `string`  if you had put a second item in the list, the print out would differ more drastically to highlight this difference.